# Path loss factor in BER calculation in Matlab for WBANs

Tags: matlab, path

Can anyone please guide me how to include path loss value in BER calculation for wireless body area networks in Matlab?
I am using qpsk modulation and Rayleigh channel.

If I simply multiply the channel with path loss value as:

```
y=x*(h*PL)+n
```

the result is that most of the values become zero.

Code (see calculation of rx, rx1, and rx2):

```
format long; bit_count = 1000000;

Eb_No = 0: 1: 30;

SNR = Eb_No + 10*log10(2);

for aa = 1: 1: length(SNR)

   T_Errors = 0;

   T_bits = 0;

   T_Errors1=0;

   T_Errors2=0;  

   while T_Errors < 10 && T_Errors1 < 10 && T_Errors2 < 10

      uncoded_bits  = round(rand(1,bit_count));

      B1 = uncoded_bits(1:2:end);

      B2 = uncoded_bits(2:2:end);

      qpsk_sig = ((B1==0).*(B2==0)*(exp(i*pi/4))+(B1==0).*(B2==1)...
      *(exp(3*i*pi/4))+(B1==1).*(B2==1)*(exp(5*i*pi/4))...
      +(B1==1).*(B2==0)*(exp(7*i*pi/4)));        

      h = sqrt(0.5*((randn(3,length(qpsk_sig))).^2+(randn(3,length(qpsk_sig))).^2));

      d1=50;

      PL1=43.22;

      PL2=67.77;

      PL3=69.8; 

      n=0.6^(SNR(aa)/0.6); 

      n1=0.7^(SNR(aa)/0.7); 

      n2=1/10^(SNR(aa)/10);  

      rx = (qpsk_sig.*h(1,:)*PL1)+ sqrt(n/2)*(randn(1,length(qpsk_sig))+i*randn(1,length(qpsk_sig)));  % Source to  Relay

      rx_re = real(rx);
      rx_im = imag(rx);      
      rxHat(find(rx_re < 0 & rx_im < 0)) = -1 + -1*j;

      rxHat(find(rx_re >= 0 & rx_im > 0)) = 1 + 1*j;

      rxHat(find(rx_re < 0 & rx_im >= 0)) = -1 + 1*j;

      rxHat(find(rx_re >= 0 & rx_im < 0)) = 1 - 1*j;
      rx1 = (rxHat.*h(2,:)*PL2) + sqrt(n1/2)*(randn(1,length(qpsk_sig))+i*randn(1,length(qpsk_sig)));  %Relay to Destination

      rx2=(qpsk_sig.*h(3,:)*PL3) + sqrt(n2/2)*randn(1,length(qpsk_sig))+i*randn(1,length(qpsk_sig)));  % Source to Destination

      %---------------------------------------------------------------

      rx = rx./h(1,:);

      rx1 = rx1./h(2,:);

      rx2 = rx2./h(3,:);

      B4 = (real(rx)<0);

      B3 = (imag(rx)<0);

      uncoded_bits_rx = zeros(1,2*length(rx));

      uncoded_bits_rx(1:2:end) = B3;

      uncoded_bits_rx(2:2:end) = B4;

      % Calculate Bit Errors

      diff = uncoded_bits - uncoded_bits_rx;

      T_Errors = T_Errors + sum(abs(diff));

      T_bits = T_bits + length(uncoded_bits);


      B8 = (real(rx1)<0);

      B7 = (imag(rx1)<0);

      uncoded_bits_rx1 = zeros(1,2*length(rx1));

      uncoded_bits_rx1(1:2:end) = B7;

      uncoded_bits_rx1(2:2:end) = B8;


      % Calculate Bit Errors
      diff1 = uncoded_bits - uncoded_bits_rx1;
      T_Errors1 = T_Errors1 + sum(abs(diff1));
      T_bits = T_bits + length(uncoded_bits);

      B6 = (real(rx2)<0);
      B5 = (imag(rx2)<0);

      uncoded_bits_rx2 = zeros(1,2*length(rx2));
      uncoded_bits_rx2(1:2:end) = B5;
      uncoded_bits_rx2(2:2:end) = B6;


      % Calculate Bit Errors
      diff2 = uncoded_bits - uncoded_bits_rx2;
      T_Errors2 = T_Errors2 + sum(abs(diff2));
      T_bits = T_bits + length(uncoded_bits);

   end

   % Calculate Bit Error Rate
   BER(aa) = T_Errors / T_bits;
   BER1(aa) = T_Errors1 / T_bits; 
   BER2(aa) = T_Errors2 / T_bits;
end

%------------------------------------------------------------ figure(1); semilogy(SNR,BER1,'bs-','LineWidth',2');

hold on;

xlabel('SNR');

ylabel('BER');

grid on;

figure(1);

semilogy(SNR,BER2,'*r');

hold on;

xlabel('SNR');

ylabel('BER');

grid on;

legend('Relay','Direct');

axis([0 30 10^-10 0.1])
```

Please help.
Thanks You

Comment: please post your code

Comment: Code added in answer tab.

Comment: please remove your answer if it's not an answer - it should be added to the questio if it's just adding more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* the zeros are acceptable, since the source->relay->destination path has 0 bit errors on occasion, whereas the direct path has > 0. When plotting in log scale, this results in the data points showing up at -Inf (off the plot).

[image]

**Edit**: I modified your code slightly to plot higher SNRs (see updated graph).  Also, I think the original usage of pathloss was incorrect.  I presume the given pathloss constants were in dB.  Those need to be converted to linear scale prior to applying them (multiplying) against the transmitted signal.  Also, the pathloss values should be *negative* dB.  The original code was essentially giving the signal a gain rather than a loss.  Here's the modified code:

```
format long; 

bit_count = 1000000;

Eb_No = 20: 1: 100;

SNR = Eb_No + 10*log10(2);  % not sure about the 10*log10 part, ??
BER = zeros(size(SNR));
BER1 = zeros(size(SNR));
BER2 = zeros(size(SNR));
for aa = 1: 1: length(SNR)

   T_Errors = 0;

   T_bits = 0;

   T_Errors1=0;

   T_Errors2=0;  

   while T_Errors < 10 && T_Errors1 < 10 && T_Errors2 < 10

      uncoded_bits  = round(rand(1,bit_count));

      B1 = uncoded_bits(1:2:end);

      B2 = uncoded_bits(2:2:end);

      qpsk_sig = ((B1==0).*(B2==0)*(exp(1i*pi/4))+(B1==0).*(B2==1)...
      *(exp(3*1i*pi/4))+(B1==1).*(B2==1)*(exp(5*1i*pi/4))...
      +(B1==1).*(B2==0)*(exp(7*1i*pi/4)));        

      h = sqrt(0.5*((randn(3,length(qpsk_sig))).^2+(randn(3,length(qpsk_sig))).^2));

      d1=50;

      % Path losses in dB
      PL1=-23.22;

      PL2=-27.77;

      PL3=-49.8; 

      n=0.6^(SNR(aa)/0.6); 

      n1=0.7^(SNR(aa)/0.7); 

      n2=1/10^(SNR(aa)/10);  

      % Since we are multiplying pathloss by the input, pathloss needs to
      % be linear (not dB).  If we keep P.L. in dB, then we would subtract
      % P.L. from the signal (which would also need to be in dB).
      rx = (qpsk_sig.*h(1,:)*(10^(PL1/10)))+ sqrt(n/2)*(randn(1,length(qpsk_sig))+1i*randn(1,length(qpsk_sig)));  % Source to  Relay

      rx_re = real(rx);
      rx_im = imag(rx);  

      rxHat = zeros(size(rx));

      rxHat(find(rx_re < 0 & rx_im < 0)) = exp(5*1i*pi/4); %-1 + -1*j;

      rxHat(find(rx_re >= 0 & rx_im > 0)) = exp(1i*pi/4); % 1 + 1*j;

      rxHat(find(rx_re < 0 & rx_im >= 0)) = exp(3*1i*pi/4); % -1 + 1*j;

      rxHat(find(rx_re >= 0 & rx_im < 0)) = exp(7*1i*pi/4); % 1 - 1*j;

      % Same as above, convert pathloss from dB to linear
      rx1 = (rxHat.*h(2,:)*(10^(PL2/10))) + sqrt(n1/2)*(randn(1,length(qpsk_sig))+1i*randn(1,length(qpsk_sig)));  %Relay to Destination

      rx2=(qpsk_sig.*h(3,:)*(10^(PL3/10))) + sqrt(n2/2)*(randn(1,length(qpsk_sig))+1i*randn(1,length(qpsk_sig)));  % Source to Destination

      %---------------------------------------------------------------

      rx = rx./h(1,:);

      rx1 = rx1./h(2,:);

      rx2 = rx2./h(3,:);

      B4 = (real(rx)<0);

      B3 = (imag(rx)<0);

      uncoded_bits_rx = zeros(1,2*length(rx));

      uncoded_bits_rx(1:2:end) = B3;

      uncoded_bits_rx(2:2:end) = B4;

      % Calculate Bit Errors

      diff = uncoded_bits - uncoded_bits_rx;

      T_Errors = T_Errors + sum(abs(diff));

      T_bits = T_bits + length(uncoded_bits);


      B8 = (real(rx1)<0);

      B7 = (imag(rx1)<0);

      uncoded_bits_rx1 = zeros(1,2*length(rx1));

      uncoded_bits_rx1(1:2:end) = B7;

      uncoded_bits_rx1(2:2:end) = B8;


      % Calculate Bit Errors
      diff1 = uncoded_bits - uncoded_bits_rx1;
      T_Errors1 = T_Errors1 + sum(abs(diff1));
      T_bits = T_bits + length(uncoded_bits);

      B6 = (real(rx2)<0);
      B5 = (imag(rx2)<0);

      uncoded_bits_rx2 = zeros(1,2*length(rx2));
      uncoded_bits_rx2(1:2:end) = B5;
      uncoded_bits_rx2(2:2:end) = B6;


      % Calculate Bit Errors
      diff2 = uncoded_bits - uncoded_bits_rx2;
      T_Errors2 = T_Errors2 + sum(abs(diff2));
      T_bits = T_bits + length(uncoded_bits);

   end

   % Calculate Bit Error Rate
   BER(aa) = T_Errors / T_bits;
   BER1(aa) = T_Errors1 / T_bits; 
   BER2(aa) = T_Errors2 / T_bits;
end

%------------------------------------------------------------ 

figure(1); 

subplot(2,1,1);

semilogy(SNR,BER1,'bs-','LineWidth',2');

hold on;

xlabel('SNR');

ylabel('BER');

grid on;

figure(1);

semilogy(SNR,BER2,'*r');

hold on;

xlabel('SNR');

ylabel('BER');

grid on;

legend('Relay','Direct');

title('Bit Errors (log)')

xlim([min(SNR) max(SNR)])

subplot(2,1,2)

plot(SNR,BER1,'bs-');

hold on

plot(SNR,BER2,'*r')

hold off

title('Bit Errors (linear)')

xlabel('SNR')

ylabel('BER')

xlim([min(SNR) max(SNR)])
```

Comment: BTW some StackOverflow trolls might yell at you that this type of question belongs in the Electrical Engineering StackExchange.  I'll just tell you nicely...  If it's truly a problem with the Matlab code and not an issue interpreting the results, then I'd suppose the question does belong here

Comment: i am new to this forum..so didnt had idea to post in the relevant stackexchange..

Comment: one thing i want to ask: without pathloss factor, the graph appears correct. means it shows almost 30 values or according to the length of loop but when path loss is added, the values becomes zero???    please help

Comment: See edit.  In general, BER should go down as SNR goes up, so the plots look promising.